# ADFS 2.0 SAML Logout

Tags: saml, adfs

This is the saml logout request sent from my SP to the IDP, I get no errors, but when I try to log back into my SP it still has my IDP cookie/session still. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong for this SAML logout?

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                  ID="_47a182d3-2a7b-46e0-9461-22c636e00b96"
                  Version="2.0"
                  Destination="https://auth.catalystapi.com/adfs/ls"
                  IssueInstant="2016-04-14T10:47:51Z"
                  >
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://localhost:7443/</saml2:Issuer>
<saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
             Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
             >msmith@catalystapi.com</saml:NameID>
<saml2p:SessionIndex>_f28d3fca-b2d6-4912-adf9-a9dde4565f0b</saml2p:SessionIndex>
```

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse ID="_d726a1e0-5863-4722-be66-e3109afa9cb8"
                  Version="2.0"
                  IssueInstant="2016-04-14T14:48:14.152Z"
                  Destination="https://auth.catalystapi.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0"
                  Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                  InResponseTo="_47a182d3-2a7b-46e0-9461-22c636e00b96"
                  xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                  >
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://auth.CatalystApi.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#_d726a1e0-5863-4722-be66-e3109afa9cb8">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>HXwA60Qo/Xnq9elhhPJVuiSsbbQ=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>ekxYz56VU37Vv9RZsZQMFS6f3whrXCSS0iiiT1NTPQ0FPipNXGxpynmFqcxFdXt7d2/nodbo5rijW4Nwr8BcuDrH9HQ2GCjuD5h/tR5VLuVC00nOXxYp9hKM5veN7ReE+yN00oMsGcTCcaX5VHcckD/FvFxQRBGF2xhn6+eCwqGGmun7TwgLQS/fpNV8a/5D6F5tXJ2+tdmv3L+ubBC1u1tWYqcFqnGxJ8vp/mwnupiRjUU5QuyVk7wcOyBd2fJezJbGGTFQlWCa/NLLwIFleQdUkiyDPVuaPaZQPvqDXOF/WajJyZ2a4+q970CXcWeTOPEeYlXkDgFtnkT7fwgBMQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</samlp:Status>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LogoutRequest`/`LogoutResponse` message exchange tells the Idp (ADFS) that it should terminate it's session. The SP is responsible for terminating it's own session itself. This is typically done by erasing the auth cookie on the same time that the redirect/POST with the `LogoutRequest` is returned to the browser.

Comment: It was actually a small issue, on the ADFS setup on the saml endpoint, but thank you for responding

Comment: @MasonSmith could you please let me know the solution or ADFS setup which solve this issue?